# Django Fields - How to prefix a field's db value based on another field's value?

Tags: python, django, field

I am trying to namespace the username field of the user object depending on the value of `is_staff`.

For example;

- Saving a user with username 'Username123' and is_staff=False will create a user object in the database with value 'customer:Username123'
- Saving a user with username 'Username123' and is_staff=True will create a user object in the database with value 'staff:Username123'

The reason for doing this is that users can be authorised through active directory or Oauth2 on a Web Application I am working on. As the username needs to be unique I am trying to use name-spacing to avoid conflicts from two users with the space username, but authorised from different sources.

I've looked into using the **from_db_value** and **get_prep_value** methods, but these don't provide the user object (thus, no way to determine the is_staff value). The **pre_save** provides access to the user model, but does not help when querying
e.g. `.filter(username='Username123', is_staff=True)` to filter Users with username `staff:Username123`

I have also tried making the username field not unique, but decided that this was a bad idea as django warns against this.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to both save and query against the prefixed value which depends on the `is_staff` flag?

Comment: What do you mean, prefix? And why? What is the reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: This looks like a very bad idea. You can better then construct a field, for example `role`, where you store the `staff`. Imagine that your username itself contains a colon, like `foo:bar`, or the role `some:role`, then the parsing can go horribly wrong.

Comment: Furthermore you can for example define a property `rendered_name` that provides such name, but then you do this on the Django/Python level.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have updated the question to include the reasons behind why I am trying to use namespaces but am open to other suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in the model that renders the value you need based on the `is_staff` value:

```
@property
def namespace(self):
   return '%s:%s' % ('staff' if is self.is_staff else 'customer', self.username)
```

I would avoid saving the `namespace` in the database because you have to maintain the value if something changes. e.g. the user is not any more staff or other changes in the creation of the namespace.

In your code just refer to `user.namespace`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Although the problem I'm having is for preserving username uniqueness (with multiple users having the same username) in the database, in which adding an additional property would not help.

Comment: You can create an unique username on the “save” of the user and combine it to create the namespace.